# event does not work the second time on first click

Tags: jquery

i wanted a simple on-off switch where when i click on the off switch the on become deactivated , and similarly when i click on the on switch.

I tried the following code, but i works fine the first time i switch, but the second time the event works on the second click.

jquery i made:

```
 var offbtnpress = true;

    $('.offbtn').click(function () {
        if (offbtnpress) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
            $(this).next('.onbtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
            $(this).next('.onbtn').removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
        }
        offbtnpress = !offbtnpress;
    });

    var onbtnpress = true;

    $('.onbtn').click(function () {
        if (onbtnpress) {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
            $(this).prev('.offbtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
            $(this).prev('.offbtn').removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
        }
        onbtnpress = !onbtnpress;
    });
```

html:

```
 <span class="btn btn-default1 pull-right borderrad2 offbtn" style="margin: 0 !important">Off</span>
                                        <span class="btn btn-primary pull-right borderrad1 onbtn" style="margin: 0 !important">On</span>
```

Please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2hLdyajp/2/

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just do a trace on the code, when `onbtnpress` is false and `offbtnpress` is false, you click `offbtn` it does not work because `btn-default1` class is already on the off button but you are adding it to the off button again so nothing happens. To create this situation, run the fiddle, click on off then on, now both are false, then click off again and you get the not working state

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
$('.offbtn, .onbtn').click(function () {
    $('span.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-default1')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2hLdyajp/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Only use one variable to track the toggle state:

https://jsfiddle.net/spefhykp/

```
var offbtnpress = true;

$('.offbtn').click(function () {
    if (offbtnpress) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).next('.onbtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
        $(this).next('.onbtn').removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
    offbtnpress = !offbtnpress;
});

//    var onbtnpress = true;

$('.onbtn').click(function () {
    if (!offbtnpress) {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
        $(this).prev('.offbtn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default1');
        $(this).prev('.offbtn').removeClass('btn-default1').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
    offbtnpress = !offbtnpress;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a solution that resembles the one @j08691 submitted, but I tried to make it more general.

https://jsfiddle.net/2hLdyajp/8/

HTML:

```
<span class="buttons noselect">
    <span class="btn btn-default pull-right borderrad2" style="margin: 0 !important">Off</span>
    <span class="btn btn-default pull-right borderrad1 btn-primary" style="margin: 0 !important">On</span>
</span>
```

I put the buttons inside a span that incapsulates them, and the only thing that differs between the buttons are the `borderrad` and `btn-primary`. Whatever class is the primary will be the selected one.

JS:

```
$('.buttons').click(function () {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('btn-primary');
});
```

The toggleClass takes care of checking the current class of the object, so you don't need to store that as a boolean variable. This method will also work if you were to include more buttons inside. Of course, I needed to change the CSS first.

---

If you need to find out which button was pressed, use this fiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/2hLdyajp/9/